# Is there any plan to add Qxt features to Qt?

Tags: qt, libqxt

[Qxt](http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/wiki/Home) is an extension library for Qt providing a suite of cross-platform utility classes to add functionality not readily available in Qt. Qxt consists of several modules, each of which lives in a separate library. It has many nice features like:

- QSlider with two buttons
- Rotating & richtext buttons and labels
- LineEdit with sample text
- managing many screen settings
- String SpinBox
- Check ComboBox
- Global Shortcut (hot keys)
- Schedule View
- Tooltip with arbitrary widget on it
- RPC(connecting signals and slots through network)
- XML-RPC
- QxtSQLPackage (Sending SQL query result through network or to a file)
- QxtSlotMapper (Map a signal to slots based on parameter value)

Qt comes with lots of new features in each release. I wonder why these useful and nice features are not included in new versions of Qt. Does anybody know if there is any plan to add these features to Qt in the future?

Comment: I don't think this is the right site to ask this question.

Comment: Unfortunately, Qxt also has a lot of anti-idioms implemented within. Since Qt is collaboratively developed, you're free to set up a jira account and start submitting code for review on gerrit.

Comment: I don't think including this to official Qt would be wise. 1st Qxt is far from mature. 2nd licensing issues Qt has commercial license sow imparted Qxt features should be also available with this license. And finally who will maintain it and pay for maintenance.

Comment: Qxt features are just good ideas for making Qt better. There is no need to add the same Qxt classes to Qt. These features can be rewrited  with more capabilities by Qt community. I think for instance it would be so promising for Qt to have some RPC method or even better something like WCF in C#.

Answer (score 1):

While I do totally understand not just sending Qxt code up stream, because it can be very kludgy, some of the things mentioned are a bit silly as to why they're not included already. The global shortcuts is the number one thing that comes to mind. Having sample text in a line edit would be another cool feature.

For a while now, in my spare time, I've been working on a note taking app, and I've specifically went with QT because of the ease of having it work cross platform compared to GTK or other GUI frameworks. One of the major concepts was having a global hotkey to make the application appear and disappear, but because QT doesn't do this on its own, I had to deal with Qxt for this one function, and it made it a giant mess to get going. I dealt with tons of bugs that prevented me from building versions for Windows. If I could, I'd gladly ditch Qxt in favor of something already baked in to QT.

Qxt grew out of a need for features that QT wouldn't include for one reason or another, and I frankly just don't understand why.